# How to allow comment tags using valid_elements in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, page-break

I'm trying to use the pagebreak plugin with TinyMCE whilst restricting the allowed elements using `valid_elements`. However, I can't figure out how to allow comment tags in my `valid_elements` setting. I've tried using `!--` but this doesn't work, although this doesn't surprise me as `!` has a special meaning in the `valid_elements` value (it makes an attribute required).

Is it possible to allow comment tags using `valid_elements`? I want to use pagebreak whilst still filtering content.

My code looks like this:-

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    plugins: 'pagebreak',
    valid_elements: 'p,br,a[title|target|href],strong,em,ul,ol,li,!--'
});
```

Comment: I have no issues adding comments to TinyMCE with varying valid_elements settings.  Can you create a TinyMCE fiddle with your exact complete init so people can see how this is removing comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my own question. To allow comments in the `valid_elements` you need to use `--[*]`. Presumably TinyMCE interprets the actual comment text as the tags attributes, so we need to include the attributes wildcard.

The code in the question needs updating to be:-

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    plugins: 'pagebreak',
    valid_elements: 'p,br,a[title|target|href],strong,em,ul,ol,li,--[*]'
});
```